# not worked nginx in docker/ laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laradock

good morning, I am a novice user in Docker. I was going to launch Docker for a Laraveli project, and when I run this project with the help of docker-compose nginx runs on port 8000, but inside the browser when it opens Reply
file docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    image: 'nginx:stable-alpine'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./Docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Docker/php/php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - Docker/mysql/mysql.env
```

file nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Folder structure:

```
ِDocker
  php
  nginx
  mysql
src
docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show docker file ?

Example for docker-compose.yml

```
#PHP Service
php_app:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: php:8.0
container_name: php_app
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
environment:
  SERVICE_NAME: app
  SERVICE_TAGS: dev
working_dir: /var/www
networks:
  - app-network

#Nginx Service
php_webserver:
image: nginx
container_name: php_webserver
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
working_dir: /var/www
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
  - ./docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
ports:
  - 8008:80
  - 446:443
networks:
  - app-network
```

Comment: PHP Dockerfike ///   FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

Comment: For the rest, I do not have a dockerfile file and I used the original image

Comment: Try with my example

Comment: Thanks it works, but it shows a 404 error and does not find the Laraveli project

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/public;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php_app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

try this nginx conf